# Applying ggplotly() on geom_bar with factors

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

I running into a problem with [plotly](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/geom_bar/) right now. I'm translating [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) graphs into interactive graphs. Here is an example code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

x <- sample(x = c(1,2), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(x = c(3,4), size = 100, replace = TRUE)


df <- data.frame(x, y)

df <- transform(df,
                x = ifelse(x == 1,"cat","dog"),
                y = ifelse(y == 3, "young","old")
                )

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x= x, fill = y)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position="none")

ggplotly(p)
```

I would expect the ggplotly function to create an interactive version but it seems that it's not able to handle factor counts.

ggplot result:
[image: ggplot result]

plotly translation:
[image: plotly translation with ggplotly]

Any suggestions to solve the issue are welcome!

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: @SBista Which versions are you using? My ggplot2 is 2.2.1 & plotly 4.7.0. Any difference to yours?

Comment: My ggplot2 is 2.1.1.9000 and plotly  version is same as yours.

Comment: code works fine for me as well

Comment: I had the same result on your example when I updated to ploty 4.7.0.  When I used `ggplotly`, though, I got a message telling me to use the development version of ggplot2.  Once I updated to that, `ggplotly` worked again on your example.